# Eigen: sparse v traditional matrix

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

To speed computation time up, I am trying to use a Sparse Matrix for the first time.  I have an existing, traditional Matrix working, Ax=b.    I'd like to use a sparse Matrix, AA*sparse_x=b.  To see if all is well, compare x with sparse_x and they should be the same...but they are not...How can I use a sparse matrix and get same answers as traditional matrix?

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(1000,1000);

//Fill A

Eigen::VectorXd b(1000);

//Fill b

Eigen::VectorXd x(1000);

x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);

    

//Sparcity is 98% for matrix A…How do I do use sparse matrix to speed things up?

//I am following: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html

std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> coefficients;

for(auto i = 0; i < A.rows(); ++i) {

    for(auto j = 0; j < Acols(); ++j) {

        const auto ij_val{ A(i, j) };

        if(!CApproximately::equal(ij_val, 0.0)) {

            Eigen::Triplet<double> trip(i, j, ij_val);

            coefficients.push_back(trip);

        }

    }

}

//Unknows

auto m = b_.rows();

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(m, m);

A.setFromTriplets(coefficients.begin(), coefficients.end());

Eigen::SimplicialCholesky<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> chol(A);

Eigen::VectorXd sparse_x = chol.solve(b);
```

Comment: Make sure you got a solution, `chol.info()==Success`, check the quality of the solution `(sparse_A*sparse_x-b).norm()/b.norm()` that should be smaller than 1e-14. If that's so, then you got a solution, and perhaps your problem admit multiple solution or your not solving the same system. To check this, you can also print `(dense_A*sparse_x-b).norm()/b.norm()`.

Comment: First of all, instead of your manual loop, you can use [`sparseView`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__SparseCore__Module.html#ga9f15dfd716fb611c0e51a3efa679c466). Also, are you sure that `A` is symmetric? You are using a QR decomposition in the dense case.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into sparseview, thanks.  A is absolutely symmetric.  I have QR because I was rotating different solvers in for speed testing...I'll put right one back in...

Comment: Deep in eigen, I found it based on you all comments.  Diag(k,k)=0.  The zero index in my matrix is unused ( as I'm learning from a Fortran author elsewhere) and zero and therfore no success for chol.  Now, traditional v sparse solutions match.  Thank you!